# Reference undefined state?

Tags: reactjs

I'm trying to achive authentification using jwt. I have a login form that sends an ajax request via an action creater to a rest API. The rest API either returns a http400 or a user object with a token. In my website header I want to show the username of a user if that user is logged in. If the user is logged in a token will be in the application state (I know, thats not the safest place for the token).

However, I can't seem to reference the token since it is undefined whenever the user is not logged in. So the question: How can I reference a piece of state if it does not exist yet?

example for header:

```
class Header extends Component {

    render() {
      return (
        <div>{this.props.auth.user.email}</div>
      );
    }
  }

  function mapStateToProps(state) {
    return { auth: state.auth };
}

export default connect(mapStateToProps) (Header);
```

I've tried:

```
if {!this.props.auth.user.name}
```

And also:

```
if {this.props.auth.user.name === undefined}
```

Both can't be rendered since the variable is not defined.

I bet a million beginners had the same problem before but I could not find a solution via search. Sorry for that.

Comment: you can also keep the reference to the name in a variable and use a fallback `const username = this.props.auth.user.name || 'Welcome'`, you can also use the `in` operator to check for a key so you don't get a cannot read key user of undefined `'user' in this.props.auth`

Answer (score 2):

You could just use an early return if the props.auth is falsy:

```
render() {
  if (!this.props.auth) {
     return null;
  }
  return (
    <div>{this.props.auth.user.email}</div>
  );
}
```